# How to find the xpath of a header title in Selenium Webdriver with Java

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I need to get the xpath of a header title that only provides the class and text itself within the 'inspect element' tab.

The goal is to have an if statement to check to see if the title of the page matches with my intended header so that I can run code that will command Selenium. The reason why I don't just use "find web elements by linkText" is because the actual content of the header is viewable in various pages. Therefor, my code would ALWAYS run since the text would always be present. I also cannot just use the class since the class name is the same for every page.

I need it to be specifically the header itself using BOTH the class name and text.

I have tried 
`if(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='className' and contains (text(),'headerText')]")) !=null)` but even if the header text doesn't match it will continue to run. I believe it would be because technically the class is present as well as the text itself although they are different elements.

Comment: Would you provide an example of HTML containing the element that should match?

Comment: IMO, you are mixing up two distinct items/elements. Its either a `Page Title` or a `Page Header`. I am not sure if `header title` makes any sense.

Comment: @DebanjanB sorry, I meant to just mean the Page header.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible points there:

1. `driver.findElements(..)` will never be null. It will return an empty collection if no matching elements found. So, use `driver.findElements(..).isEmpty()` to handle case when nothing was found
2. Try using `contains(.,'headerText')` instead of `contains(text(),'headerText')` if still no elements found. The first option will work when your header text element contains some child tags / formatting tags.

Comment: I tried out your second option and worked wonders, thank you very much!